# I want a linux command to find all users on your system whose user ids are greater than 11?

Tags: linux

Is there a linux command I can use, to find all users on my system whose userid is greater than 11?

Comment: A simple `awk` command run against `/etc/passwd` should do it. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i want to find number of users on your system whose user ids are greater than 8 in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072255/i-want-to-find-number-of-users-on-your-system-whose-user-ids-are-greater-than-8)

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look at the file [`/etc/passwd`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd).  It lists all the users on your system and their user IDs (the third field).

You can print all the user names (first column) with UID > 11 with this AWK command:

```
    awk -F: '$3>11{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score -1):

If your system using LDAP/AD/NIS better to go with below command.

```
#getent passwd |awk -F: '$3>11{print $1,$3,$5}'
```